# OpenUI5, oData v4: How to use server-side pagination via $skiptoken

Tags: odata, sapui5

In the release notes of OpenUI5 it says that since 1.72 server side pagination is supported.
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.72.1/#/topic/25e532617b7f4b9bad842757324151ed.html

But I can't see any reference to it, how it is used, how it is activated.
My questions are in particular:

- Must the $metadata contain anything special to enable that?
- How to force UI5 to send a $skiptoken URL parameter

Thanks in advance

Comment: What’s your use case? The control can handle growing or you have to supply your desired value at api call.  In any case URL is created as needed. There is no need to check this by hand

Comment: The use case is that server side pagination should be used instead of client side paging via $skip/$top.